Spring boot @RestController throwing 404
I have two rest controllers on the same package level with following code:
First controller:

    @Slf4j
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(API + NO_AUTH + "/payments/method")
    public class PaymentMethodController {
    
      private final PaymentMethodService paymentMethodService;
    
      @GetMapping("/{parentId}/{schoolId}/all")
      public List<PaymentMethod> getAllCardsForParent(
          @PathVariable final Long parentId, @PathVariable final Long schoolId) {
        return paymentMethodService.getPaymentMethodCards(parentId, schoolId);
      }
    
      @PostMapping("/{parentId}/{schoolId}")
      public SetupPaymentMethodResponse generateSetupToken(
          @PathVariable final Long parentId, @PathVariable final Long schoolId) {
        return paymentMethodService.createPaymentMethodSetupToken(parentId, schoolId);
      }
    }

Second controller

    @Slf4j
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(API + NO_AUTH + "/payments")
    public class PaymentController {
    
      private final CapturePaymentService capturePaymentService;
    
      @PostMapping("/create")
      public CapturePaymentResponse createPaymentForActivity(
          @RequestBody final CapturePaymentRequest capturePaymentRequest) {
        return capturePaymentService.createPayment(capturePaymentRequest);
      }
    
      @PostMapping("/{paymentId}/confirm")
      public void capturePayment(@PathVariable Long paymentId) {
        capturePaymentService.captureSubscription(paymentId);
      }
    }


Both the controllers are at same package level. I am able to hit the PaymentMethodController but I am not able to hit PaymentController.
ApplicationStarter i.e. SpringBoot main class is at the root of the project.
I think the URI might be conflicting but I am not sure why this issue is happening.
I can run this on local as well and I am able to hit both controller but after deployment it is not working for PaymentController.
